# How to set project dependencies in XCode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode

I had a project setup properly in XCode 4, but now it seems to be a gamble in XCode 5. I have library projects that need to be built before the main one. Basically:

Main Project depends on Lib A
Lib A depends on Lib B and C

For some reason, Lib A is sometimes not being built before the Main Project causing a linking error. This doesn't happen all the time so its like a race condition. Is there some new way of specifying a strict order in XCode 5?

Addendum:

So previously my structure was:

```
Main Project 
+
|- Lib A
   +
   |-Lib B
   |-Lib C
```

And this didn't seem to work (all the time anyway).

Then I tried

```
Lib A
+
|- Main Project
+-Lib B
+-Lib C
```

The structure is how the project are in my workspace. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Usually going to the project build phases and add your dependency targets works.

Answer (score 0):

In the Xcode 5, click on the project file and Choose a target. Now under "Build Phases" there is a "Target Dependencies" setting. You will need to create a target for compiling Lib A beforehand if the main project depends on Lib A.

Comment: I guess this is part of my confusion. I do have it set as a target dependency.